# How can I solve an orthogonal-constrained Sylvester equation?

Tags: matrix-equations, orthogonal-matrices

I am currently facing a Sylvester equation

$AX+XB = C$

where $A$, $B$, $C$ are all symmetric and a special constraint here is that $X$ should be orthogonal. The Sylvester equation itself may not hold perfectly and hence the least-square solution is also ok.

Comment: Try a numerical solution first, e.g., $\min_{X^TX=I} \|AX+XB-C\|_F$ using http://manopt.org

Comment: If you relax $X^T X = I$ into $X^T X \preceq I$, you have a semidefinite program.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I should have made my expression more clear. That is, I prefer an analytical solution rather than a numerical one. And regarding to relax it into a semidefinite program question, may I say that the solution is still not analytical?

Comment: @lisi Analytical solutions are a luxury and a rarity.

Answer (score 3):

Let me assume that $A$ and $-B$ have no common eigenvalues. Without the orthogonality constraint there is then a unique solution $Y$ of the Sylvester equation $AY+YB=C$, which you can find using [known methods.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) Let $Y$ have the singular value decomposition $Y=U\Sigma V^T$. Then $X=UV^T$ is the orthogonal matrix that minimizes $\sum_{ij}(X_{ij}-Y_{ij})^2$. (For a proof, see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2215359/87355))

Comment: I got it! Thank you!